# HBase table design

Tags: hbase

I am fresh to HBase, recently we plan to use HBase to store & query data. But met a couple of questions when I try to create some demo tables:

1. What's the usage of ColumnFamily? As all the columns must belong to one CF and the wiki suggests to only define CF, it confuse me on defining this?
2. Seems we could only query the data via row key(like the Primary key in RDBMS), but how could we query through other parameters if we do NOT know the row key value?
3. If query via non-row key columns, will the performance be affected?

Thanks
Ivan Geng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the usage of ColumnFamily? As all the columns must belong to one CF and the wiki suggests to only define CF, it confuse me on defining this?

ColumnFamily can be used to organize data. But it is more than that. Physically, all column family members are stored together on the filesystem. Because tunings and storage specifications are done at the column family level, it is advised that all column family members have the same general access pattern and size characteristics.

> Seems we could only query the data via row key(like the Primary key in RDBMS), but how could we query through other parameters if we do NOT know the row key value?

Depends on your scenario. There are various Filters available. Please refer : [Filters in HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.filter.html)
You can think of RowKey as the built in Indexed filter. If you apply a filter on any other column then it is not indexed and hence the performance is nowhere close to RowKey based GET.

> If query via non-row key columns, will the performance be affected?

As indicated above it is much more inefficient to query with Filters on other columns.

Comment: Thanks Venkat, I will look into the filters. Any reference for table design best practice in HBase? As I am still thinking in the RDBMS way when creating the table :(

Comment: I think this is the best starter guide : http://hbase.apache.org/book/schema.html

Answer (score 0):

ColumnFamily are used to organize your columns (group them) and add some flexibility as you can add a new column in a column family anytime you want without affect actual data. HBase is NoSQL oriented but I've been using Phoenix, a SQL skin for HBase, in order to apply SQL queries on HBase data. With Phoenix you can create SQL queries with WHERE clauses and performances are pretty good take a look [HERE](http://phoenix.apache.org/). Otherwise you can create a composite key to sort your data but it depends on your data and what you're going to do with it ...